# Build a dictionary from two entities from EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dictionary, entity

I have two tables which used to generate two entities. For example: issue and owner (one owner can own multiple issues, not vice versa). Now I want load these into memory at run time for performance reason (to look up owner give an issue). So I think I can have dictionary Dictionary(IssueEntityComparer).
How do I build up this dictionary in C#?

Comment: Your `Issue` entity doesn't have a navigation property pointing back to its `Owner`?

Comment: It does have FK to Owner.OwnerId.

Comment: So given an `Issue`, can't you use `Issue.Owner` to get the `Owner`?  Why would you need a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var map = db.Issues
.Select (i => new { Key = i.IssueId, Value = i.OwnerId })
.ToDictionary (i => i.Key, i => i.Value);
```

Comment: This seems good, I missed some details in question. The key of the issue dictionary is the issue entity (name, type to uniquely identify an issue), the key is the owner entity, which should include the owner name, owner email etc.